# Create new record does not work in Jquery Kendo subgrid

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I am using Jquery Kendo grid to show records. The grid has sub grid. Create new records works fine for outer most parent grid but when I click on create new record button in sub grid, noting happens. There should be a blank row created where I can enter data. Is there any configuration needed for this?

Comment: Can you add a [dojo](https://dojo.telerik.com/) exemple in your question ?

Comment: Agree with "DontVoteMeDown".  You need to give us some example code.  You using MVC or Javascript kendo.  Plus, Kendo isn't part of Jquery.  It's Telerik's.  Jquery is another API for javascript, you can often use them together though.